# Executing code after user has been authenticated using Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an ASP.NET MVC Core (1.1.0) application using VS2015. In the dialog, I selected the option to connect to Azure AD, so VS generated the boilerplate code and, as expected, the app redirects me to Microsoft's login page, where I can login with my work&school account.

Now, after the user logs in, and before serving the first page (say, /home/index) I need to get some information from the user that I have stored in a database (like the display name, the contact information such as an email, phone number, address, a picture of the user, and so on).

What I have thought so far is to add a ControllerBase with a method that retrieves this info, and then pass it to the views via ViewData. But querying the database for this info over and over seems inefficient. An alternative would be to store this info in a cookie or in a session state, thus only hitting the database once. But having to depend on a ControllerBase could lead to errors (for instance, if in some controller method one forgets to call the base's method) and doesn't feel like they way to go. Also, having this funcionality on the home controller only could fail if a user enters the URL with a predefined path (as in www.myapp.com/Users/joedoe/Detail).

I searched and found a reference to using the Events property in the OpenIdConnectOptions object passed to the application builder in the Startup class:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
    CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"],
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
        //
    }
});
```

However, the OpenIdConnectEvents class does not have some "OnAuthenticationSucceeded" event, it only has an OnAuthenticationFailed, which is not what I want, and other callbacks whose names doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

So, my question, what is the callback I should be using with OpenIdConnectEvents, or, alternatively, what's the preferred way for ASP.NET MVC Core applications that connect to AAD to catch an event after the user has been authenticated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an assortment of various `OpenIdConnectEvents` you can hook into. Look at `SecurityTokenValidated`. This fires after the user has authenticated to AAD and the token had been validated. Here you can look up data in a database and add your own claims to the identity (like roles, etc).

This sample goes and resolves group names from AAD, but the concept is the same - add additional data to the claim set and you can access it through the user principal throughout the application. Using a ClaimType of role will let you use the existing attributes in ASP.net (like the `Authorize(Role=...)` attribute.

https://github.com/jpda/azure-ad-netcore-sample/blob/master/src/azure-ad-netcore-sample/Startup.cs

Comment: Thank you John! Setting the OnTokenValidated property with a callback fuction did the trick, as you said. And the example provided is great, I was planning to use session state but claims seem a better option, as in the example you provided. Thanks again.